# Show that $(n+1)^{n-1}<n^n$ using the binomial theorem

Tags: analysis, binomial-theorem

I want to show that $(n+1)^{n-1}<n^n$ using the binomial theorem.

I have done the following:\begin{align*}\left (n+1\right )^{n-1}&=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{k}n^{n-1-k}1^k=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{k}n^{n-1-k}\\ & <\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{k}n^{n-1}=n^{n-1}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{k} \\ & =n^{n-1}\cdot 2^{n-1}<n^{n-1}\cdot n^{n-1}=n^{2n-2}\end{align*} This is not correct.

What could I change to get the correct result?

Comment: if $n = 1$, does your inequality hold?

Comment: @MathLover: Probably a typo, since later $(n+1)^{n-1}$ is evaluated.

Comment: Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1146294/42969.

Comment: Is $3^3 < 2^2$ a valid statement? If you meant $(n+1)^{n-1} < n^n$, edit the question accordingly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that $(n+1)^{n-1}&lt;n^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1146294/prove-that-n1n-1nn)

Comment: It should be apparent that $2^{n-1} > n$ for any $n \geq 3$, so your first inequality, for which the right side equals $n^{n-1} 2^{n-1} > n^{n-1} \cdot n = n^n$, is necessarily too coarse.  You would need a finer estimate than simply $n^{n-1-k} \leq n^{n-1}$

Comment: I am glad that you showed work.  If you hadn't, I would have offered the counter example that $6^6$ is not less than $5^5$.

Comment: Oh yes, there is a typo. It should be $(n+1)^{n-1}<n^n$.

Comment: So, is it better to apply induction instead of the binomial theorem? @MartinR

Comment: So, is it better to apply induction instead of the binomial theorem? @thedumbkid

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean! I edited it! @Deepak

Comment: How could we get a finer estimate? @BrianMoehring

Comment: There are many proofs of that inequality (you probably can find more with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24(n%2B1)%5E%7Bn-1%7D%3Cn%5En%24)). I don't know if there is a proof using the binomial theorem.

Comment: Ok! Thank you!! :-) @MartinR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is equivalent to showing that
$\left(1+\frac1n\right)^{n-1}<n,$ that is, that

$$1+n\left(\frac1n\right)+\frac{n(n-1)}{2}\left(\frac1n\right)^2+\cdots+\left(\frac1n\right)^{n-1}<n.$$

But this is true since the expansion can be rearranged thus

$$ 1+1+\frac12\left(1-\frac1n\right)+\frac{1}{3!}\left(1-\frac1n\right)\left(1-\frac2n\right)+\cdots+\frac{1}{n^{n-1}},$$ from which it is obvious that the inequality follows, since the expansion is less than $$\underbrace{1+1+1+\cdots+1+1}.$$

Comment: Thank you!! :-)